# How to return a reference to a global variable OnceLock?

Tags: rust, reference, global-variables

I'm trying to implement a derive-macro which would implement a trait for handling global variables. Say, there're some enum types and I would like to have a separate `OnceLock` for each enum. In that case, there's a need for a handle to get it in a general way. The problem lies in the returned `lifetime`s.

```
use std::sync::OnceLock;

const v: OnceLock<Vec<u32>> = OnceLock::new();

trait GetGlobal: Sized {
    fn get_global() -> &'static OnceLock<Self>;
}

impl GetGlobal for Vec<u32> {
    fn get_global() -> &'static OnceLock<Self> {
        &v
    }
}

fn main() {
}
```

The code above generates the following error:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return reference to temporary value
  --> ./ex_110.rs:11:9
   |
11 |         &v
   |         ^-
   |         ||
   |         |temporary value created here
   |         returns a reference to data owned by the current function
```

How should I go about remedying it? Not to mention, that it would be better off returning a reference to the underlying data, via `OnceLock::get()`. Still, it spawns the same `lifetime` error.

Comment: `v` should not be `const` but `static` (and uppercased to conform to Rust's style guide).

Comment: @JonasFassbender , OnceLock is presupposed to be shared between threads, isn't it? I need a global variable, not thread-local. Whereas static is a thread local thing, isn't it?

Comment: No, `static` is global (see the answer I submitted). Thread local stuff can be defined with the [`thread_local!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.thread_local.html) macro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having `v` as a constant won't work. Roughly speaking, constants evaluate to expressions that are copied to the locations they are used in, so your `&v` becomes `&OnceLock::new()`, hence creating a temporary value. `static` items on the other hand are a concrete location in memory. Make your `OnceLock` a `static` variable. From the docs of [`static`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.static.html) (emphesized by me):

> On the surface, static items seem very similar to consts: both contain a value, both require type annotations and both can only be initialized with constant functions and values. However, statics are notably different in that they represent a location in memory. That means that you can have references to static items and potentially even modify them, making them **essentially global variables**.

Here's your code with `static` replacing `const` and it compiles on the [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f36d51d47bf6a8de1c659330bfc9f695):

```
use std::sync::OnceLock;

static V: OnceLock<Vec<u32>> = OnceLock::new();

trait GetGlobal: Sized {
    fn get_global() -> &'static OnceLock<Self>;
}

impl GetGlobal for Vec<u32> {
    fn get_global() -> &'static OnceLock<Self> {
        &V
    }
}

fn main() {
}
```

Comment: Note that _usually_ it works because of static promotion, but here static promotion doesn't kick in because `OnceLock` contains interior mutability.